# Read two files from the keyboard and print line 1 of the first file, line 1 of the second file

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that reads two files from the keyboard and prints line 1 of the first file,
line 1 of the second file, line 2 of the first file, line 2 of the second file, and so on. This is how the output should look like:

```
File 1 line 1
File 2 line 1
File 1 line 2
File 2 line 2
File 1 line 3
File 1 line 4
```

My code works and prints the output but with the incorrect format. The output of my code looks like follows:

```
File 1 line 1
File 2 line 1
File 1 line 2
File 2 line 2File 1 line 3
File 1 line 4
```

This is my entire code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp, *fp2;
    char str[50];
    char str2[50];
    char firstFile[50], secondFile[50];
    int counter;

    printf("Enter the first filename: ");
    gets(firstFile);

    fp = fopen(firstFile, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
   {
      printf("Can't open the file!\n");
      exit(1);
   }

    printf("Enter the second filename: ");
    gets(secondFile);

   fp2 = fopen(secondFile, "r");
   if (fp2 == NULL)
   {
      printf("Can't open the file!\n");
      exit(1);
   }

   printf("\n");

   while( fgets(str, 30, fp) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", str);
        while(fgets(str2, 30, fp2) != NULL){
            printf("%s", str2);
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("\n");

   fclose(fp);
   fclose(fp2);
}
```

I tried implementing a `printf("\n")` inside the second loop in order to fix the format but it won't work properly. I do not understand why the `if` statement inside the loop is not working. I tried this with no luck:

```
 while( fgets(str, 30, fp) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", str);
        for( int i = 0; fgets(str2, 30, fp2) != NULL; ){
            printf("%s", str2);
            if(i == 1){
                    printf("\n");
}
            else{
                    i++;
}
            break;
        }
    }
```

These are the files I am using to run this code:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P6W3dJHVvLOuRjj2NvEbOzic2uFocbKC/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z-2OXuLIxwroOgUJaTvTUyhrBguv4ZJH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: *Never* use `gets`

Comment: 30 is a pretty small buffer.  With `fgets`, if any lines of input are too long, you will not get the newline until the next (or the 5th or 6th or 100th) call to fgets and will wind up printing a lot of data from the file with no intervening newline.  That seems to match the problem you describe.

Comment: @WilliamPursell What should I use instead?

Comment: You should simplify the logic so you don't need to read a full line at a time.  If you need to read full lines, you either need to add logic around `fgets`, or accept a max line size, or use `getline`. In this case, you only need to read one character at a time.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not really line oriented, and trying to read one line at a time from each file is more complicated than it needs to be.  You only need to read one character at a time, and change the input file from which you are reading whenever you see a newline.  eg:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE * xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode);

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        FILE *input[2];
        int idx = 0;
        input[0] = xfopen(argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "input1", "r");
        input[1] = xfopen(argc > 2 ? argv[2] : "input2", "r");
        int c;
        while( (c = getc(input[idx])) != EOF ){
                if( c == '\n' ) {
                        idx = !idx;
                }
                putchar(c);
        }
        while( (c = getc(input[!idx])) != EOF ){
                putchar(c);
        }
        return 0;
}

FILE *
xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
        FILE *fp = path[0] != '-' || path[1] != '\0' ? fopen(path, mode) :
                *mode == 'r' ? stdin : stdout;
        if( fp == NULL ){
                perror(path);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        return fp;
}
```

Comment: I understand the logic behind your code and explanation but I am just starting to learn about files in C so it is quite difficult to translate what you have showed me into my own code.